# Client WebServiceException has ResponseStatus null without explicit ResponseStatus

Tags: error-handling, client, servicestack

I am quite new to ServiceStack, I am following the example at http://nilsnaegele.com/codeedge/servicestack1.html which I have been finding useful.
I read that explicit StatusResponse fields in DTO Response declarations were not required in the new API, but I dont appear to be getting the expected behaviour here.

Using ServiceStack 3.9.71.

I introduced an Exception in the EntryService post to get a feel for the client handling.

```
public object Post(Entry request)
{
    if (request.Quantity == 3)
    {
        throw new WebException("post entry");
    }
}
```

With

```
public class EntryResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the client side when posting an Entry handle the exception.

```
    try
    {
        var entryRequest = new Entry {Quantity = quantity, EntryTime = DateTime.Now};
        var response = client.Send(entryRequest);
        Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", response.Id);
    }
    catch (WebServiceException wse)
    {
        // At this point wse.ResponseStatus field is null.
    }
```

I tested out explicitly adding the ResponseStatus field to EntryResponse and this produced the ResponseStatus filled in on the client with no change to the client code.

I then tried throwing an exception in StatusRequestService as follows to see if the second web service client request would behave the same way, and it appears it behaves differently.

```
public object Any(StatusRequest request)
{
    if (request.Lever == 3)
    {
        throw new WebException("get status.");
    }
}
```

With the following.

```
public class StatusResponse
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Goal { get; set; }
}
```

Then catching this in the client as per

```
try
{
    var postResponse = client.Post<StatusResponse>("status", new StatusRequest { Date = DateTime.Now, Lever = 3 });
    Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1} achieved", postResponse.Total, postResponse.Goal);
}
catch (WebServiceException wse)
{
    // At this point wse.ResponseStatus field is valid and filled in.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `{RequestDto}Response` convention and also ensure a ResponseStatus is returned you have to opt-in and add it to the Response DTO, e.g:

```
public class StatusResponse
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Goal { get; set; }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

This is because there is an [explicit exception for Responses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#error-response-types) that follow the convention `{RequestDto}Response` naming convention:

#### If it exists:

The `{RequestDto}Response` is returned, regardless of the service method's response type. If the `{RequestDto}Response` DTO has a **ResponseStatus** property, it is populated otherwise no **ResponseStatus** will be returned.  (If you have decorated the `{ResponseDto}Response` class and properties with `[DataContract]/[DataMember]` attributes, then **ResponseStatus** also needs to be decorated, to get populated).

#### Otherwise, if it doesn't:

A generic `ErrorResponse` gets returned with a populated **ResponseStatus** property.

The [Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) transparently handles the different Error Response types, and for schema-less formats like JSON/JSV/etc there's no actual visible difference between returning a **ResponseStatus** in a custom or generic `ErrorResponse` - as they both output the same response on the wire.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Why does it work for the second example above then ? It works for StatusResponse class with out explicit field, and doesn't for EntryResponse with out explicit field. Is there some other difference between these two cases that I am missing ?

Comment: @RobinLuiten Because your Request DTO is called **StatusRequest** not **Status**

Comment: LOL... I think I am to close to the tree... Thank you :)